# setRating not working on an inflated layout-Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parse-platform, layout-inflater

I am currently trying to set the rating of rating bar in another view, but whenever I try to set the rating, nothing happens (no errors or anything).  To give some context, I have a Google map fragment and I am trying to set the rating bar's rating in the marker content window from the map fragment itself.

Thanks in advance

Here is all of my code:

```
query.whereContains("review", titleRev);
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {

                            for (ParseObject parseObj : scoreList) {
                                int x = 0;

                                String ratingNum = parseObj.get("rating").toString();
                                float ratingNumF = Float.valueOf(ratingNum);
                                myList.add(x, ratingNumF);

                                x++;
                            }

                            float sum = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                                sum += myList.get(i);
                            }


                            if (sum > 0) {
                                final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();

                                final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.windowlayout, null);

                                RatingBar ra = (RatingBar) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.windowRatingBar);
                                ra.setRating(1f);




                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(FindOpp.this, "Sorry, this organization has no reviews", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually ended up fixing this problem by getting a reference to all of my markers on the Google map and then adding the ratings to a string set which correlated with the marker.getTitle(), and I average the results in the getInfoWindow.